# ZIO [Declarative] Transactional Management

Tags: scala, transactions, zio, doobie

I spent a lot of time figuring out transactions on my otherwise well running `ZIO+HTTP4S+Doobie`-project.
How can I have proper [declarative] transaction management? Something like Spring `@Transactional`.
I read this very good post [from-transactional-to-type-safe-reasonable-transactions](https://blog.softwaremill.com/from-transactional-to-type-safe-reasonable-transactions-a5019906245e), but ironically have exactly the alleged Spring challenge of getting confused how/where the transactions are precisely handled :)
Also tried [tranzactio](https://github.com/gaelrenoux/tranzactio), even a entered a [question](https://github.com/gaelrenoux/tranzactio/issues/15) under issues, where my PR (on my fork) seems to indicate individual `transact` calls are grouped in a single transaction?!

And [here in bootzooka](https://github.com/softwaremill/bootzooka/blob/master/backend/src/main/scala/com/softwaremill/bootzooka/Main.scala#L21) which is on the ZIO references list, I don't understand why the Resource is 'used' only once in main, and then `transact` is called around the logic. Well, I understand why it works, but I don't see any 'Strategy' or anything else letting me handle when an error in the first ZIO-effekt would let me control what happens to the second flatmapped effect...

Or how to assure there will be a single transaction happening for a HTTP4S-request.

Or an error handler, that got a `@RequiresNew` to actually store information about the error somewhere in the databse, even when all the previous logic is correctly rolled back.

I wouldn't mind helping others by writing up something about this, but I clearly have more to learn. About Doobie and ZLayers and so forth.

If there is something I am clearly missing here, please let me know :-)

Comment: can you, please, write some example?
what you trying to achieve is unclear

Comment: _Or how to assure there will be a single transaction happening for a HTTP4S-request._
 - you just write transact once - it is simplier and more explicit than the bean magic
|||
_letting me handle when an error in the first ZIO-effekt would let me control what happens to the second flatmapped effect..._ 
- you can use something like recoverWith/handleWith to process error in a (Z)IO